# how to extract only the vertices with multiple edges from a graph using igraph in R

Tags: r, graph, igraph

I am new to igraph and graph theory. I have a very large file (> 4 GB) and I was told it is a graph. I can see the format includes the pairs separated by tab and I can read it as a table first then convert it to graph data frame.

Number of vertices with `vcount` and number of edges with `ecount` suggest that there are vertices with multiple edges. I have been looking at various sources but I could not find the information about directly extracting the vertices with more than one edges.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I guess I was wrong with the terminology. What I meant by vertices with multiple edges is called 'articulation_points'.

This was what I was looking for:

```
library(igraph)
bi <- biconnected_components(g)
bi$articulation_points
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the edges incident to each vertex (if `g` is your igraph)

```
 ie <- igraph::incident_edges(g, igraph::V(g))
```

Then, to get the number of edges adjacent to each vertex

```
num.incident.edges <- sapply(ie, length)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip, not quite the answer to my question but very useful.

Comment: Must have misunderstood the question then, glad you sorted it out!